# Remove by column in pandas.DataFrame.hist

Tags: python, pandas

After specifying grouping by column `a` and restricting to column `f` and `g` for histogram, I still have column `a` showing up in green. Is there a way to remove it without going into matplotlib or for loop?

```
axes = dfs.hist(column=['f', 'g'], by='a', layout=(1, 3), legend=True, bins=np.linspace(0, 8, 10),
            sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

Comment: It would certainly have helped to provide sample data... see [reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the reminder. Indeed I should have included example data. Nice to have ALollz to include it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly a bug with the pandas library. The problem seems to arise when `by` is a numeric dtype column -- it probably subsets the DataFrame to the labels in `column` and `by` and then plots that, which is problematic when `by` is numeric.

You can either create non-numeric labels for the column that defines your `'by'`, or if you don't want to change your data, it suffices to re-assign the type to `object` just before the plot.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'length': np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000),
                   'width': np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000),
                   'a': np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000)})
```

---

```
# Problem with a numeric dtype for `by` column
df.hist(column=['length', 'width'], by='a', figsize=(4, 2))
```

[image]

```
# Works fine when column type is object
(df.assign(a=df['a'].astype('object'))
   .hist(column=['length', 'width'], by='a' , figsize=(4, 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. Changing the data type is a neat way. Will open an issue on pandas github.